# .NET Exception not being caught when using RAISERROR function in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have read so much on the RASIERROR function and its requirements for making the exception raise in .NET, but I still can't get the exception to be rasied.  Here is the SP snippet:

```
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('This is a custom error message.', 16, 1);
    RETURN;
END
```

And here is the .NET code snippet:

```
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'Close the db connection, and local dispose
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As SQLException
        Dim msg As String = ex.Message
    End Try
```

So I *think* I have covered the bases:

- Severity level above '10' (using 16)
- Catching SQLException type (although it inherits from Exception so shouldn't matter I would think
- Using 'ExecuteNonQuery'
- Within SQL Enterprise Manager, when I run the stored proc directly, **I do get the error** : *"Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
  This is a custom error message."*

So what am I missing? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you give the complete code for the procedure? Are you sure that the RAISERROR code is being called?

Comment: That cmd object is just a plain old SqlCommand, right?  If so, my only other guess would be that your RAISEERROR is called from inside a T-SQL TRY block?

Comment: Yes I know it is being called by evidence of my 3rd bullet point: •Within SQL Enterprise Manager, when I run the stored proc directly, I do get the error : "Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 This is a custom error message."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine for me:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("...");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "errTest";
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

CREATE PROCEDURE errTest
AS
    RAISERROR('This is a custom error message.', 16, 1);
RETURN;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out; all of the code I posted worked as is 100%. Silly mistake on my part. The severity level *was* set to '16' but the actual sp had not been executed (I was working off a 'debug' version created by EM that represented the sp; right-click 'debug') and was still set to '10'. Once the update occured .NET immdeatly trapped the exception. Thanks for helping anyways, I do appreciate it.

Comment: Always use SQL Profiler first to determine what might be going on.

Comment: Agree 100%. I am a .NET developer at heart, and not a SQL guy (except when I have to be), so I make mistakes here and there. Thanks for the suggestion.